# Lots of "object reference not set to an instance of an object" questions

Tags: support, questions, title

I noticed there are a lot of questions with the title of "object reference not set to an instance of an object" or similar, with little or no other clue as to what the problem is about.

Is there a policy about the title of these types of questions?  Should there be?  Should I edit the title to be more specific?

Comment: Wipe them out. All of them.

Comment: Question reference not set to an instance of a question

Comment: "Should I edit the title to be more specific?" Sure, edit the title to "Please tell me to spend 2 minutes to debug my own code and then close this."

Comment: If they're .NET questions, then you should close as a duplicate of [this canonical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net).

Comment: @TheEstablishment I'm sure there is a Java equivalent too.

Answer (score 4):

Generally these questions are "Too Localized" as the conditions under which that exception occurs (no matter the technology) are very specific to the code that the poster wrote.

That said if that's the case then vote to close as such; if it's an old question with little chance of garnering the close votes required, flag for moderator attention.

If on the off chance that the question isn't specific to the code the user wrote, but about a common case that occurs in the technology (i.e. it will serve as the canonical reference in this case), and it *isn't* a dupe of an existing question, then by all means keep it open.

Comment: OH COME ON!!!!!

Comment: @Adam I see you've woken from your slumber.  It's do-or-die time buddy.  Oh, see all that rep-whoring from the whole Coke-can on DSP thing? Yeah... =)

Comment: @Adam be comforted that I have to beat the rep cap (with just one accepted answer) in order to get to 10K first.  You don't have that burden.  Good luck.  It all comes down to today!

Comment: I win.  Cue fireworks.

Comment: @Adam Well played!  Congrats, you can retire on top now =)

Comment: Meh, if I were in NY I might celebrate with lunch at Fraunces Tavern.  Instead I think I'll celebrate at Panera Bread :-|

Comment: @AdamRackis Well, technically I could be ahead of you by the end of the day.  Are we going by first to 10K or who is further at the end of the day (I'm 10 away now)? =P

Comment: I think the contest was clearly first to 10K :-)  But regardless, you're capped, and you'd need 4 checkmarks to surpass me.  If you can pull that off I'll buy you a beer next time I'm in the city.

Comment: You need [5 checkmarks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129561/155403) now, and counting :-)